# single workflow for same list in different subsites (SP 2013 Workflow)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, custom-lists

I have the following structure in my Sharepoint:

- Parent Site (site collection)

  - Project A (subsite)

    - Orders List
  - Project B (subsite)

    - Orders List
  - Project C (subsite)

    - Orders List

---

**Orders List** is the same for all subsites.
I'd like to create a single workflow that will work for all **Orders List**.
If I create a workflow for each list on each subsite, maintenance will be hard.. Will have to update all workflows separately once one is changed.

I've looked into workflow attached to content types but it doesn't work in SP 2013 Workflow.

What is the best way I can do this? Maybe create a workflow on the parent site that works for all subsites calling same list.

Comment: we can create a reusable workflow on a content type in sharepoint Designer 2013. Here is the link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

Comment: Hi Rohit! Thanks for your response! I tried the link but I'd like the workflow to be available on the entire site collection, including its subsites. When I created the workflow on the link you sent, it is only available on the current site. Workflow 2010 has the option to publish globally. Is there a way to do this also with workflow 2013?

Comment: Can you try this link. I have not tried it but you can give it a try -- http://pravahaminfo.blogspot.in/2011/04/reusable-and-globally-reusable.html

Comment: this one also - http://talkingsharepoint.visualsp.com/sharepoint_1/SharePoint/sharepoint-designer-2013/creating-globally-reusable-workflows-for-other-site-collections-and-other-sharepoint-farms/

Comment: Thanks for the links! but they are applicable only to workflow 2010, not workflow 2013. I'd like to create mine using workflow 2013. I have already searched and read pages through the net. Maybe if it's not possible, I'll just consider using 2010 platform. Thanks!